# creating a function that outputs true or false if a number is a prime number?

Tags: haskell

I have a function called primeTest that should output True or false for every n element to infinity whether its a prime or not.

```
divides :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool 
divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

prime :: Integer -> Bool
prime n = n > 1 && and [not(divides x n) | x <- [2..(n-1)]]

allprimes :: [Integer]
allprimes = [x | x<- [2..], prime x]


primeTest :: [Bool]
primeTest = [x | x<- [2..], prime x]
```

I tried calling the all primes function but get the error that it cannot match type Integer to Bool, any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of your `primeTest` function is identical to that of your `allprimes` function; both definitions have type `[Integer]`, so of course that’s going to conflict since you just told it you would provide a `[Bool]`.

Probably, what you meant to do was rather than generating *the list of elements such that that element is prime*, you mean to generate *for each element, whether that element is prime*. Think about it:

```
[             | x <- [2..],            ]
  ^                          ^ condition on whether to include it in the list
  what to include in the final list
```

Comment: so take x out of what to include instead of that is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions for `allPrimes` and `primeTest` are exactly the same, so if `allPrimes` is a list of Integers, you shouldn't be surprised that `primeTest` is also a list of Integers and not a list of Bools that your type signature asserts.

The simplest definition for `primeTest` that makes sense is:

```
primeTest :: [Bool]
primeTest = [ prime x | x<- [2..] ]
```

This is the same as:

```
primeTest = map prime [2..]
```

Is this what you were looking for?